# css - Postion:fixed works on desktop but not mobile

Tags: html, css, position

I am creating a page for comments, which containers users' comments and a comment input, the comment input is fixed at the bottom.
The problem is it works fine on Desktop, but when I try on my iPad iOS 11 the comment input box scrolls with the page, not fixed at the bottom.
Here is my code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1z0s6ay/12/)

CSS

```
.xi-ipad-scroll {
  height:500px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:green;
}
.xi-comment {
  width: 40%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
.xi-comment-box {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.xi-comment-send {
  bottom: 15px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="xi-ipad-scroll">
  <div class="xi-main-title">Bình luận</div>

  <div class="xi-comment-list">
    <ul>
      <li>
          <div>Quang Anh Nguyễn</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum prompta sadipscing cu sit. Ea mei lorem erroribus honestatis, laoreet torquatos eu mel, nam dicant labitur tractatos et. Cu est alia altera consulatu, vim falli detracto reformidans in, novum forensibus eu sit. At etiam erroribus prodesset qui, eam veniam laoreet at. Ea mei natum erant.</div>
      </li>
      <li>....</li>

    </ul>
  </div>

    <div class="xi-box xi-comment">
      <textarea type="text" placeholder="Comment..." class="resizable xi-comment-box" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>


</div><!--iPad-->
```

I searched on internet and I got solutions like putting `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` or `z-index:100` but none of them works

Comment: are you looking for the comment to be at the bottom of the page, and not in the bottom corner of the browser at all times?

Comment: Yes, I want the comment box to be fixed in the bottom of xi-iPad-scroll div

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly, your "position:fixed" is actually what is causing this. Fixed position will always show on the screen. [More info on fixed position.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) If you want it to be at the bottom of all content you will need to remove the fixed from both -send and -comment.

```
.xi-comment {
  width: 40%;
  bottom: 0;
  ***position: fixed;***
}

.xi-comment-send {
  bottom: 15px;
  ***position: fixed;***
}
```

This now leads to a new problem, you have set an absolute height and have hidden anything outside of that height. You either need to extend the height, remove the hidden, or move the comment section outside of that div.

I put together a [codepen](https://codepen.io/chris-hitchcock/pen/WKgxyq?editors=1100) to show this. I think you actually are having the same issue on desktop, I just don't believe you had enough content for you to realize it.